# combining strings of n length in a list python

Tags: python

Whenever I use permutations, I have to create a list of the permutations because it returns a 'itertools.permutations object at 0x0190A5D0'. Then after I create the list, I have to combine the strings in each list so that I have the permutation I wanted originally. If it is a number, then I have to make them all integers again.

Two part question:

1) Is there an easier way to do a permutation and create the list of numbers?

2) Below I've created a permutation of a number with 5 digits. However, where I have '12345', I want the user to input their own number. Thus the formatting string b=['s%s%s...] will have to be n %s  and n x. Anyone know how to do this?

(FYI my program is trying to find the next largest number with the same digits given a user's input so 12345 next largest is 12354)

**Both questions were answered below please see both responses. Thanks!!!**

```
def nexthighest():
    from itertools import permutations
    numb = str(12345)
    a = list(permutations(numb))
    b = ['%s%s%s%s%s' % xxxxx for xxxxx in a]  #<-- this is where the n length problem occurs
    c = list(map(int,b))
    for i in c:
        if i >12345:
            print(i)
            break
```

Comment: Your basic algorithm is broken -- e.g., if you use "897" as your input, then the first permutation you find that's larger than i will be 987, which is *not* the next largest number with the same digits (978).  One way to fix it would be by replacing `list(map(int,b))` with `sorted(map(int,b))`.  A better way would be to do `numb = sorted(str(input_value)`.

Comment: To solve your problem, you don't need _all_ permutations, just one - namely the next in lexicographic order. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) for the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to build all those lists. Just loop over the return value from `permutations`, joining and parsing as an integer each permutation as it comes by:

```
def nexthigher(n):
    for p in permutations(sorted(str(n))):
        i = int("".join(p))
        if i > n:
            return i
```

Comment: Next higher for n=54321 returns None.  45321 returns 54321, but 51234 is next highest.

Comment: @larsmans thank you! I didn't realize that "permutations object at ..." implied it was already in the background and that I could just call it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Tolonen hmmm any reason why that is? Does it need to be sorted?

Comment: To fix this to do what the OP actually wants, replace `permutations(str(n))` with `permutations(sorted(str(n)))` (or `sorted(permutations(str(n)))` would also work)

Comment: Thanks @EdwardLoper Thought it was that

Comment: Also need to handle the case where the original n **is** the highest number, which `None` might be what you want.  Better to be explicit and add `return None` after the `for`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: then the function will return `None`, which I consider the correct answer.

Comment: @EdwardLoper: thanks for the `sorted` idea. I consider `sorted(permutations(str(n)))` a waste of memory, though.

Comment: @larsmans Agreed -- That's why I recommended `permutations(sorted(str(n)))` first.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer part two for you:

```
b = ["".join(x) for x in a]
```

Comment: Omg I can't believe I'm such a noob. I had the same code without the '[]' and the result was I created a string of 123451235412435...Thanks!

Comment: Youre welcome. Its a little trick used to convert a list/tuple to a string by concatenating each value with an empty string.